# What does it mean by pruning and enrichment in the case of Rosenbluth method?

Tags: monte-carlo, polymers, atomistic-simulation

As far as I understand:

1. Pruning means deleting something.
2. Enrich means to enhance/increase weight.

Now my question is, in the case of [pruned-enriched Rosenbluth method](https://arxiv.org/abs/1107.1214) (PERM):

For pruning/enriching, are we deleting/adding to some polymers chains or are we deleting/adding some beads in all polymer chains?

Basically, when we are updating the weights, what are we replacing them with?

Comment: +1. I wonder if during the last 6 months you figured out the answer? You're welcome to write a self-answer if you figured it out.

Comment: This post appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if OP addresses questions/suggestions in the comments.